# VSCode Install Modules from Command Line

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to install VSCode Modules/Extensions from the command line or via Powershell?

I would like to deploy unattended installations with the Modules/Extensions already installed

Comment: what are `VSCode Modules`

Comment: Are you talking about VSCode extensions?

Comment: Yes, exactly about that

Comment: Is just a "install recommended extensions? [install]" popup not enough?

Answer (score -1):

Use `code --install-extension <ext-id | path>`

Directly from `code --help`:
[image]

Comment: why are we answering this? this is a duplicate

Answer (score -1):

It is possible. The [documentation of VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace#_command-line-extension-management) describes the operations that can be performed with extensions using the command line:

> To make it easier to automate and configure VS Code, it is possible to list, install, and uninstall extensions from the [command line](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line). When identifying an extension, provide the full name of the form `publisher.extension`, for example `ms-python.python`.
>
> Example:
>
> ```bash
> code --extensions-dir <dir>
>     Set the root path for extensions.
> code --list-extensions
>     List the installed extensions.
> code --show-versions
>     Show versions of installed extensions, when using --list-extension.
> code --install-extension (<extension-id> | <extension-vsix-path>)
>     Installs an extension.
> code --uninstall-extension (<extension-id> | <extension-vsix-path>)
>     Uninstalls an extension.
> code --enable-proposed-api (<extension-id>)
>     Enables proposed API features for extensions. Can receive one or more extension IDs to enable individually.
> ```

You can always get this information (together with the other command line options) by running in your terminal:

```bash
code --help
```

The command you are looking for is:

```bash
code --install-extension <extension-id>
```

Replace `<extension-id>` with the ID of the extension you want to install. You can find the extension ID in VSCode, in the extension details page (see the bottom-right corner of the image below)

[image: The extension details page of the ESLint VSCode extension]

You can also find the extension ID on the [extension's page in Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint), roughly on the same area of the page (it is called "Unique Identifier").

Comment: why are we answering this? this is a duplicate